# Detecting file reload in Apache Commons Configuration2

Tags: config, apache-commons, apache-commons-config

Using `org.apache.commons:commons-configuration2:2.1` my application needs to know when a configuration file has been reloaded so that it can update some things in the program. Apache Commons Configuration2 uses a lot of strategies and factories, and usually that's great, but here it's getting so complicated I can't figure out where I need to install a listener.

The application has this:

```
configConfigurationBuilder = new ReloadingFileBasedConfigurationBuilder<FileBasedConfiguration>(
    PropertiesConfiguration.class)
        .configure(new Parameters().properties().setFile(getConfigFile()));
final PeriodicReloadingTrigger configReloadingTrigger = new PeriodicReloadingTrigger(
    configConfigurationBuilder.getReloadingController(), null, 1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
configReloadingTrigger.start();
```

Which of these various things can I install a listener on? I just want to be notified when the configuration file is reloaded.

I notice that the `ReloadingDetector` interface has a `reloadingPerformed()` method, and that sounds like what I want. But how do I add my own `ReloadingDetector`? It seems like the `ReloadingController` only keeps one `ReloadingDetector` around. Surely I don't have to subclass `ReloadingDetector` and install a custom one, would I? I'm not wanting to specialize the reloading detection, so subclassing would not be appropriate --- I just want to be notified when something happens. Besides, it's not obvious to me where I would even hook into the `ReloadingFileBasedConfigurationBuilder` chain of events where it uses some internal factor to create the detector.

So how can I easily get Apache Commons Configuration2 to notify me when it reloads a configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I posted this question to the [Apache Commons mailing list](http://mailto:user@commons.apache.org), and Oliver Heger replied:

> You can add an event listener at the ReloadingController, then you
>   receive notifications of type ReloadingEvent.
>
> Alternatively, you could also register a more generic listener for
>   events on the configuration builder itself. When the builder's managed
>   configuration is reset, a corresponding event is produced. This also
>   happens during a reload operation.

At first I was confused about whether these events are sent out when the need for a reload is detected or after the reload has occured, but he reminded me:

> Maybe a misunderstanding of the reloading mechanism: New data is not
>   automatically pushed into a Configuration object you might have a
>   reference to. Rather, the configuration builder is reset. So the next
>   time you query the builder for a configuration you get a new one with
>   updated data.
>
> When you receive one of the mentioned events the builder has been reset
>   and thus you know that new data is available.

That was a useful answer, which I'm sharing to help others. (I wish the Apache Commons developers monitored and were active on Stack Overflow.)